# Nested sortable script for Mootools 1.2.0

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2, nested-sortable

Does anyone know of a Mootools script that provides nested sortable but also works on Mootools 1.2.0 ?

All the nested sortable scripts I can find require newer versions - but I'm stuck with 1.2.0 as it's part of the core components of the system I'm extending..

Thanks

EDIT: The main ones I've found where:

[Ryan Mitchel's script](https://github.com/ryanmitchell/Nested-Sortables/): looked great. 1.3 required though

[Mif Tree](http://mifjs.net/tree/Download/Builder/): more than I needed. requires 1.2.4 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think Mif.Tree is easiest. Just remove the parts you don't need.

Found an old copy that's compatible with mootools 1.2: http://pastebin.com/MaZuSQcG

Comment: Thanks for digging up a 1.2 compatible version. I'll have to get back to that project and try it out.